# How to call webservice client from java in JAXWS

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

I want to call the Webservice client from my servlet or java class in eclipse.

And how to use the client to call a particular method in wsdl from my java or servlet class?

Comment: Didn't you try anything, e.g. generating the JAX-WS client stubs?

Comment: yeah created and tested. I don't know how to call particular webservice method is WSDl from my client which is called from servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/
    helloservice/hello?wsdl")
static HelloService service;
...  

Hello port = service.getHelloPort();

....
String response = port.sayHello(name);
```

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html